# Divide orders based on order number and items ordered

Tags: export, sku

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this: 
Compare order if it has multiple items with this same SKU it will be given a different status. 
for instance order :
555 has 3 items all with sku 565 < single 
556 has 3 items all with different SKU's < multiple

i understand that logic isn't sophisticated, get items ordered if items 1 sku equals item2 sku ... and so on .

is there a way to place within magento2?

best solution would be an order export single . order export multiple. 
where only orders containing single sku orders would be exported and another one where only orders that have varied items would be exported . 
Any idea where to start ? 
thanks , 
[image]